# Übersetzen: "And I, by suggesting, ..."

Tags: sentence-structure

Wie würdet ihr diesen Satz kurz und knackig übersetzen?

> "And I, by suggesting, *ever so delicately, that you might want a great career, must* hate children."

([Kontext)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKHTawgyKWQ&feature=player_detailpage#t=589s)

Mein Vorschlag:

> Und das impliziert, dass ich Kinder hasse.

**Edit**: On second thoughts, this translation is more accurate I think:

> Und es deutet an, dass ich Kinder hasse.

Comment: Du hast den Satz aus dem Video stark verkürzt. Ich bezweifle, daß er so, wie er oben steht, überhaupt etwas Sinnvolles bedeutet.

Comment: Wie ich es verstehe, sagt er: _And I, by suggesting, ever so delicately, that you might want a great career, must hate children._

Comment: "Indem ich auch nur zart andeute das Sie sich eine erfolgreiche Karriere wünschen zeige ich das ich Kinder hasse" (ich habe das Video nicht gehört (keinen Kopfhörer dabei), aber so eine Formulierung würde am ehesten jemand nehmen der den Eindruck hat dass ihm eine bestimmte Haltung unterstellt wird, insofern wird meine Übersetzung der Intention vielleicht nicht ganz gerecht).

Comment: @user160446: könntest du dazu schreiben, wo genau der Satz gesagt wird? Dann müssen nicht alle das ganze Video gucken.

Comment: @Emanuel: Die genaue Stelle ist im Link enthalten: `...#t=589s` = bei 589 Sekunden (9:49 Minuten).

Comment: @chirlu: hat bei meinem Browser nicht gefunzt. Danke.

Comment: Das "und das", bzw. "und es" kann ja nicht zu einem schöden "And I" passen. In gesprochener Rede kommt es aber oft zu Auslassungen, Sprüngen, Wechsel von Zeit und Person so dass es mir als gute Vorbereitung der Frage scheint zumindest eine Transkription des Audioschnipsels zu besorgen, so dass man eine gemeinsame Ausgangsbasis hat, und nicht schon darüber streitet, was überhaupt gesagt wurde.

Answer (score 1):

> *And I, by suggesting [...] that you might want a great career, must hate children.*

könnte man wie folgt übersetzen:

> Eigentlich muss ich, unter der Annahme, dass man eine großartige Karriere plant, Kinder hassen.

Man darf den eingeschobenen Satz mit der Karriere also nicht einfach weglassen, da sich *suggesting* im Original genau darauf bezieht.

*Anmerkung:*
Im gesprochenen Original wechselt Larry Smith den Bezug von "ich" auf "du", was im Deutschen so nicht so einfach funktioniert. Deshalb mein Ausweichen auf *"man"* und die Wiederherstellung zum "ich" mit "eigentlich".

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass "you" hier "du" heisst. Siehe Definition 3 im [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/you)

Comment: Ich denke schon, daß es ein _du_ ist. Angesprochen ist das imaginäre Gegenüber, das gerade gesagt hat, daß es seine Vorstellungen von Freundschaft, Partnerschaft, Elternschaft nicht auf dem Altar des Erfolgs opfern werde. Wenn Smith nun wieder das Thema Super-Karriere anschneidet, kann dieses Gegenüber nur folgern, daß Smith Kinder hassen muß.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht wieso er, unterstellend der andere strebe die Karriere an, der Kinderhasser sein soll. Ich meine aber das ähnlich gehört zu haben und vermutte es ist dieses problematische mündlich, bei dem sowas passiert, nur so ein Exempel dann zum Übersetzen auszuwählen ... - und nebenbei, ich schlage vor "unterstellen". `Unterstellen wir mal, Sie streben solch eine große Karriere an, dann müssen Sie Kinder hassen.` - das wäre ein Satz, den ich verstehen könnte. Ich bin aber fern von sicher was nun gemeint ist.

Comment: _May I suggest_ daß _suggest_ hier _vorschlagen, nahelegen_ heißt? Wenn er auf das Thema tolle Karriere zu sprechen kommt, kommt das bei den Adressaten als Empfehlung an, ihre Kinder im Stich zu lassen.

Comment: @chirlu: Das kommt hin.